# Python: how to keep a big numpy array of arrays of floats relatively small?

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point, out-of-memory, uint8t

I have a numpy array created from reading many images with the cv2 package. I read the image in grayscale so the pixel values are from 0 to 255 in which case the type of the data is uint8. This means each data element is of size 1 byte. I create a list using each image and then want to transform the list of arrays into an array of arrays. Afterwards, I need to feed this data into a model but the model needs the image pixel values to be floats between 1 and 0. Now each float in Python is 8 bytes. So I tried to transform each array using this cv2 function

```
unlabeled_img_array = cv2.normalize(unlabeled_img_array.astype('float'), None, 0.0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

It works and I can create the list of arrays. The problem arises when I try to turn the list of arrays into an array of arrays with this:

```
unlabeled_img_array_arrays = np.array(unlabeled_img_list_arrays)
```

I then get a Memory Error, evidently because the matrix is too big. If I do it with datatype uint8 there's no error.

My question is. Is there a way to get over this problem or would I have to stick with using uint8 instead of float values?

Edit:

I also tried using this

```
cv2.normalize(unlabeled_img_array.astype(np.float16), None, 0.0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

but it gives me this error

```
TypeError: src data type = 23 is not supported
```

Is there a way to make the array to float16? Maybe that will cut the size enough. Although I'm not sure if the model will accept it.

Comment: Instead of an array of numbers, is it possible to use a Python string and manipulate the individual bytes?

Comment: @tadman not sure I follow. You mean using strings instead of the float values? I don't think the model will accept an array of strings though. It specifically checks if the values are between 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding your question. If you can do the math with integer only then that's the most efficient way to store it. If you need floats, would 32-bit (4-byte) single-precision floats work?

Comment: @tadman the problem is that the data needs to be fed on a model that is not mine and the model asks for floats. I also printed the itemsize of the array and it shows 8 after converting to float. Shouldn't it be 4? Also single-precision can be more than enough since I need only to represent 255 values.

Comment: On I get it now, the function is using float64 as default I guess. I'll try float32 then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try 'float16' instead of 'float', this would nominally save 3/4 of the memory.

Comment: Yes I managed to avoid the problem by using np.float32 instead of just "float" on the cv2 normalization function. So float32 was enough. I will still mark this answer as acceptable. Thanks